# remove numbered keys from json

Tags: javascript, regex

my json looks like this:

```js
{
  '0' : 'nice',
  '1' : 'awesome',
  'test' : 'again',
  'bla': 'good'
}
```

What I want to get is this:

```js
{
  'test' : 'again',
  'bla': 'good'
}
```

basically if keys are just numbers, they shouldn't be in the new json.

Is there any clean way to do this ? possibly with regex and one liner ?

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier without using regex?

See [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const source = {
  '0' : 'nice',
  '1' : 'awesome',
  'test' : 'again',
  'bla': 'good'
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(source).filter(([key]) => isNaN(key)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A reduce version

```js
const source = { '0' : 'nice', '1' : 'awesome', 'test' : 'again', 'bla': 'good' };

const result = Object.entries(source).reduce((acc,[key,val]) => {
  if (isNaN(key)) acc[key]=val; 
  return acc;
}
,{})

console.log(result);
```